# Web API model binding error ("No parameterless constructor defined for this object.")

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm pretty new to ASP NET Web API, but have got some experience in MVC. 
I'm trying to implement IModelBinder for binding [PhysicalAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress(v=vs.110).aspx) using Web API 5.2.3. Here's the code for it:

```cs
public class PhysicalAddressModelBinder : FromStringModelBinderBase<PhysicalAddress>
{
    protected override bool BindFromString(string value, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var addressUnformatted = PhysicalAddressFormatter.ToNonFormattedPhysicalAddress(value); // returns string without delimiters
            var physicaladdress = PhysicalAddress.Parse(addressUnformatted); 
            bindingContext.Model = physicaladdress;
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            bindingContext.Model = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class FromStringModelBinderBase<T> : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(T))
            return false;

        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (val == null)
            return false;

        var str = val.RawValue as string;

        if (str == null)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName,
                $"A string is needed to populate {bindingContext.ModelType} but a {val.GetType().Name} was provided.");
            return false;
        }

        if (BindFromString(str, bindingContext))
        {
            return true;
        }
        bindingContext
            .ModelState
            .AddModelError( bindingContext.ModelName, $"The string \"{str}\" cant be presented as {typeof(T).Name}." );

        bindingContext.Model = null;
        return false;
    }

    protected abstract bool BindFromString(string value, ModelBindingContext bindingContext);
}
```

I register the binder in WebApiConfig using

```cs
config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(PhysicalAddress), new PhysicalAddressModelBinder()));
```

Then I try to bind a model:

```cs
public class DeviceModel 
{
    public PhysicalAddress MacAddress { get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult Unregister(DeviceModel model)
{
    //do stuff        
}
```

Everything goes fine if the MacAddress string provided is valid -- I get a model with the populated value.

But when the address string is invalid (PhysicalAddress.Parse(addressUnformatted) throws a FormatException), the code

```cs
bindingContext
.ModelState
.AddModelError( bindingContext.ModelName, $"The string \"{str}\" cant be presented as {typeof(T).Name}." );
```

works well, then some some stuff happens in the Web API engine, but when I get to the controller, the ModelState doesn't contain my error, but it does contain the following error:

```cs
ErrorMessage: ""
Exception:  {"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."}   
Exception stack trace:
System.Exception {System.MissingMethodException}
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.MutableObjectModelBinder.EnsureModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) 
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.MutableObjectModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContextExtensions.Bind(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, IEnumerable``1 binders)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexModelDtoModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContextExtensions.Bind(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, IEnumerable``1 binders)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.MutableObjectModelBinder.CreateAndPopulateDto(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, IEnumerable``1 propertyMetadatas) 
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.MutableObjectModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContextExtensions.Bind(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, IEnumerable``1 binders)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.CompositeModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormDataCollectionExtensions.ReadAsInternal(FormDataCollection formData, Type type, String modelName, HttpActionContext actionContext)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormDataCollectionExtensions.ReadAs(FormDataCollection formData, Type type, String modelName, IRequiredMemberSelector requiredMemberSelector, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, HttpConfiguration config)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter.<ReadFromStreamAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
```

It looks like the internal binders/formatters are trying to bind the property again, failing to do it because of the absence of the parameterless ctor in PhysicalAddress. But why does that happen? And where goes my error from the ModelState?

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to search for similar issues, but without any luck. Any advice would be highly apprecialted.

Comment: Try instantiating your `PhysicalAddress` object in the property `MacAddress`. Like `public DeviceModel() { MacAddress = new PhysicalAddress(); }`.

Comment: PhysicalAddress doesn't contain a parameterless ctor indeed, so you can't instasntiate it this way. I tried this way:
public DeviceModel()
        {
            this.MacAddress = PhysicalAddress.None;
        }
but it didn't work. The result was the same.

Comment: What is the constructor of your `PhysicalAddress`?

Comment: This is not my `PhysicalAddress`, this is the .NET [PhysicalAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In this case, try using a setter on the property in your `DeviceModel`. Like `public PhysicalAddress MacAddress { get; set { MacAddress = new PhysicalAddress(value) } }`. It should work. Let me know!

Comment: Nah, it's a workaround. And I want a normal solution.